# Can we create routes using firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, web, routes

We can create routes like
**

```
app,.get(function(req, res){
  res.render("xyz.ejs")
})
```

**
using express.
Can we use firebase with node for creating such routes?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the question properly can you please rephrase it

Comment: Can I use firebase for backend totally. For database, routes, authentication??

Comment: you can do auth, and the database i'm not sure about routing because firebase is not a language it's a platform. maybe for that, you can check firebase cloud functions to create serverless architecture.